# How To Cancel a Notification When Android App is Closed By Swipe?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

When you close the app by swiping it in recent apps, it will cancel any services and terminate most aspects of the app gracefully. However, if there are any notifications that were SetOngoing(true), then these will remain if the app suddenly is closed, and there aren't any services that listen for the app's termination.

What is the right way to deal with this problem?

Recently, I coded a music player, and I arranged it such that in the OnStop for my activities, the notification is canceled (and so is the thread updating the progress bar within it). Then, OnResume, I trigger the notification again.

If they "recent apps swipe" it away, or click away, the notification goes away now, as long as the music isn't playing. So to get rid of the notification, you have to pause it, and then swipe away. Otherwise, there is a leak memory if the app is closed by swipe, where the notification remains open and is buggy afterwards if the app is reopened, and the app crashes if you click the notification (though maybe that's because I can't figure out how to get started with saved state bundles). Likewise, there is a problem if you let the app close the notification every OnStop, as then it will be closed as the user does other things with their phone, even though the music is playing (which sort of defeats the point of it right?)

Are there other better ways to handle this? Who has a good saved state bundle if that is indeed relevant to my issue?

Thanks for the discussion

Comment: Are you using https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services?

Comment: Indeed I am! It's a foreground service that has a MediaPlayer and other components (it's a smart music player).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so, after much dabbling and dozens of work hours... I have found the best way to handle this issue is to create a MediaBrowserService with a MediaSession. In the notification creation code, it is very particular about how you start that notification (which has to be in the Foreground and bound to the MediaSession). Once this is done, the notification will stay open, even if you close the app, and clicking it will always bring you back to the activity bound to the service (see the supplied code below). Then, you just have a button on the notification to close itself and the app. Voila, a notification that does NOT remain open if the app is closed from the recent apps, etc.

```
    public static void CancelNotificationBreadCrumb()
    {
        if (cts != null)
        {
            cts.Cancel();
            Thread.Sleep(250);
            // Cancellation should have happened, so call Dispose
            cts.Dispose();
            MyLogger.Debug("MyMediaPlayer: CloseEntireApp: Notification should have been disposed.");
        }
    }

    public static void NotificationNowPlayingBreadCrumb()
    {
        try
        {
            Intent intent = MenuManager.GetGoToNowPlayingIntent(context, GetCurrentlyPlaying());

            manager = (NotificationManager)context.GetSystemService(NotificationService);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 1, intent, PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);

            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(ChannelId, ChannelId, NotificationImportance.Low);
            notificationChannel.EnableLights(false);
            notificationChannel.EnableVibration(false);
            notificationChannel.SetSound(null, null);
            //notificationChannel.SetVibrationPattern(new long[] { 10, 20 });
            manager.CreateNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

            Notification notification = NowPlayingAdapter.InflateNotification(context, currentFile, ChannelId, pendingIntent);
            service.StartForeground(MY_MEDIA_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

            manager.Notify(MY_MEDIA_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

            // Then trigger the thread to update the real-time features
            if (cts == null || cts.IsCancellationRequested)
                cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(RunInBackground), cts.Token);
        } catch(Exception e)
        {
            string message = "MyMediaPlayer: NotificationNowPlayingBreadCrumb: Could not create now playing breadcrumb notification; message: " + e.Message;
            MyLogger.Error(message);
        }
    }

    public static void CloseEntireApp()
    {
        MyLogger.Trace("MyMediaPlayer: Entering CloseEntireApp...");
        if (player != null)
            player.Release();

        CancelNotificationBreadCrumb();

        MediaReceiver.Dispose();
        MediaSession.Dispose();


        MyLogger.Trace("MyMediaPlayer: CloseEntireApp is Killing App. Good bye!");
        service.StopSelf();
        Android.OS.Process.KillProcess(Android.OS.Process.MyPid());
    }
```

Here is the OnCreate method for my service:

```
public class MyMediaPlayer : MediaBrowserServiceCompat
{
    private static MediaPlayer? player;
    private static MusicAppFile? currentFile;
    private static List<MusicAppFile>? allFilesInCurrentContext;
    private static Context? context;
    private static List<int> recentIndexes = new List<int>();
    private static int maxRecentIndexes = 30;
    private static bool shuffleMode = false;
    private static ViewGroup? Parent;
    private static NotificationManager? manager;
    private static CancellationTokenSource? cts;

    public static MediaButtonReceiver? MediaReceiver;
    public static MediaSessionCompat? MediaSession;
    private static PlaybackStateCompat.Builder stateBuilder;
    private static MediaBrowserServiceCompat service;

    public IBinder Binder { get; private set; }

    public const string ActionPlay = "com.xamarin.action.PLAY";
    public const string ActionPause = "com.xamarin.action.PAUSE";
    public const string ActionNext = "com.xamarin.action.NEXT";
    public const string ActionStop = "com.xamarin.action.STOP";
    public const string ActionBack = "com.xamarin.action.BACK";
    public const string ActionCloseApp = "com.xamarin.action.CLOSEAPP";

    public static string ChannelId = "NowPlayingNote";
    public static string MY_MEDIA_ROOT_ID = "media_root_id";
    public static int MY_MEDIA_NOTIFICATION_ID = 1111111;
    public static string MY_MEDIA_TAG = "media_tag";

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();

        // Create a MediaSessionCompat
        MediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(context, MY_MEDIA_TAG);

        // Enable callbacks from MediaButtons and TransportControls
        MediaSession.SetFlags(
              MediaSessionCompat.FlagHandlesMediaButtons |
              MediaSessionCompat.FlagHandlesTransportControls);

        // Set an initial PlaybackState with ACTION_PLAY, so media buttons can start the player
        stateBuilder = new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
                            .SetActions(
                                PlaybackStateCompat.ActionPlay |
                                PlaybackStateCompat.ActionPlayPause |
                                PlaybackStateCompat.ActionSkipToNext |
                                PlaybackStateCompat.ActionSkipToPrevious |
                                PlaybackStateCompat.ActionStop);
        MediaSession.SetPlaybackState(stateBuilder.Build());

        // MySessionCallback() don't do this. C# isn't as good at doing callbacks because you can't define them inline
        // MediaSession.SetCallback(new MediaSessionCallback(this));
        
        service = this;

        // Set the session's token so that client activities can communicate with it.
        SessionToken = MediaSession.SessionToken;
    }
...
```

I create this service when they click to select a file in one of the menu activities (so in a method called by a method called by an OnClick delegate):

```
if (musicMenu != null)
{
    bool stillPlayingSameFile = MyMediaPlayer.UpdateCurrentContext(c, musicMenu, mf);

    if (cts == null)
    {
        // Start the service and tell it to call play
        InitiateMediaBrowserService(c);
     } else
     {
        MyMediaPlayer.Play(stillPlayingSameFile);
     }
 }
 GoToNowPlaying(c, mf);
```

and the inner service there:

```
    public static void InitiateMediaBrowserService(Context c)
    {
        // Start the service and tell it to call play
        Intent intent = new Intent(c, typeof(MyMediaPlayer));
        intent.SetAction(MyMediaPlayer.ActionPlay);

        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Platform.AppContext.StartForegroundService(intent);
    }
```

Ok, so now the play service, which is triggered from the action play intent here, and makes the call to start the notification, which is where the StartForeground call is made (see the first snippet at the top):

```
    public static void Play(bool stillPlayingSameFile)
    {
        // If the player has not been created before, or it is a new track, then it needs to be recreated
        if (player == null || !stillPlayingSameFile)
        {
            // If we're here to recreate the player, destroy the old one in memory first
            if (player != null)
                player.Release();

            // Then add the new player
            if (currentFile != null)
            {
                Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(currentFile.FilePath);
                MediaPlayer media = MediaPlayer.Create(context, uri);
                media.Completion += OnCompletion;

                if (MediaReceiver == null)
                    MediaReceiver = new MediaButtonReceiver(context);

                media.RoutingChanged += MediaReceiver.OnRoutingChanged;
                player = media;
                player.SetWakeMode(context, WakeLockFlags.Partial);
                
            }

            // Finally, add this file to the list of those recently played
            int indexToPlay = allFilesInCurrentContext.IndexOf(currentFile);
            if (indexToPlay >= 0)
                recentIndexes.Add(indexToPlay);

            if (recentIndexes.Count > maxRecentIndexes)
                recentIndexes.RemoveAt(0);

        }

        // Finally start the player, which picks up where left off if this is the same track

        if (!IsPlaying() || !stillPlayingSameFile)
        {
            player.Start();
            NotificationNowPlayingBreadCrumb();
        }
    }
```

The MediaButtonReceiver and MediaBroadcastReceiver classes are pretty straightforward, so comment if you really need that code. One other thing to note is that you do have to bind the service to an activity (I suggest the now playing activity):

```
    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        base.OnStart();

        //Config.ConfigureBluetoothIntegration(this); TODO remove this
        
        Intent serviceToStart = new Intent(this, typeof(MyMediaPlayer));
        //serviceToStart.SetAction(MyMediaPlayer.ActionPlay);
        BindService(serviceToStart, new ServiceConnection(this), Bind.AutoCreate);
    }
```

So there, now there IS an example of how to use the MediaSession and MediaSessionCompat and MediaBrowserServiceCompat online somewhere. Even ChatGPT could not find an example or tell me how to do this. You are welcome, internet. Enjoy your coding!

Answer (score 1):

You can cancel the notification when android App is closed by swipe with the following code:

```
      [Service]
      public class ForegroundServiceDemo : Service
      {
           
            public override void OnTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent)
            {
                  //this.StopSelf();
                  //this.StopForeground(StopForegroundFlags.Remove);
                  this.StopService(new Intent(this,typeof(ForegroundServiceDemo)));
                  base.OnTaskRemoved(rootIntent);     
            }
           
      }
```

By overriding the `OnTaskRemoved` method of the service, the system will call this method when user closes the app by swipe. And each of the three lines code can cancel the notification and stop the service when the app is closed by swipe.

Comment: No, actually. This service doesn't get called when the app crashes or is terminated by the OS because of memory issues, or for other reasons. This will leave the notification, which will cause all sorts of issues with the healthy termination of the app until it is force closed by the OS. Thanks for commenting, though!

Answer (score 0):

I found this, finally, after trying every search terms imaginable, and wow there is a whole section on this. I do not have it working yet, but I can report back with code when I do. Here is the solution: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/media-apps-overview

Seems you have to implement the media player service as a specific kind of service that registers to the notification. I am in the process of refactoring the heart of my code, which perhaps should be terrifying, but feels more like the final algorithm on a Rubix's cube... I will report back in like 10 work hours with some working code (I hope).

Thanks to everyone contributing on this discussion!

Comment: On second thought, don't use this method. Why would you use C# if you wanted to mess with callbacks? Use delegates! They're better

Comment: Use link formatting